# Listener doesn't get called when calling with a separate thread

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, binding, listener

I've been trying the implement a slot machine with javafx + threads.
My `Reel` class `extends Thread`. This is the run method of the Reel Class. It basically spins till user Clicks the real. Reel Class has activeImage (Object Property  )

```
    @Override
public void run() {
    spinning = true;
    spin();
}


public void spin() {
    while (spinning) {
        for (Symbol symbol : symbolList) {
            System.out.println("Running");


            activeImage.set(symbol.getImage());

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000); // or whatever
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and I've implmeneted a Listner in the GUI Class.

```
      slotMachineHandler.getSlotMachine().getReelList().get(0).activeImageProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Image>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Image> observable, Image oldValue, Image newValue) {
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    activeImg1.setImage(slotMachineHandler.getSlotMachine().getReelList().get(0).getActiveImage());
                }
            });

        }
    });
```

but my problem is the listener is not getting called when I start the reel with different thread. but when I try to set active image using the main thread, listener gets called perfectly. I've used bindings aswell. Same result. Would be really nice if anyone can show me some light ;)

Comment: Like most GUI toolkits, JavaFX requires all methods to be called in a single thread—the JavaFX application thread.  If you attempt to call JavaFX methods in other threads, they may fail in unpredictable ways.  Place your call to `activeImage.set` inside a [Platform.runLater](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-) call.

Comment: Did. but still its not working. Full code - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Kvp_JXDVBgypGHqWgv-zT6FVuWrZgW1V please help out if you have some itme

Comment: You may have better luck binding the values:  `activeImg1.imageProperty().bind(slotMachineHandler.getSlotMachine().getReelList().get(0).activeImageProperty());` Then you won’t need a ChangeListener at all.